# Infinite scroll and masonry on image folder contents

Tags: php, jquery, infinite-scroll, image-gallery, masonry

Title says it all really.

I need to load the images in a folder on the server to a web page, and apply both infinite scroll and masonry to them.

I have done a bunch of research, and not quite found the ideal solution. The main issue I can't seem to solve is how to apply pagination to said images, which seems to be a requirement of Infinite Scroll (unless I have misunderstood the documentation).

If you have a solution that involves SQL, then may I ask that you keep the explanation as detailed as possible, as I have basically no experience of using it. I am relatively comfortable with PHP and jQuery/javascript though.

Also, the design is responsive. I'm sure that information isn't hugely important, but just in case...

**This is my code so far:**

**HTML & PHP**

```
<div id="photographs">
<?php $title = get_the_title();
    $folder_path = "wp-content/themes/them_name/images/photos/$title/";
    $images = glob($folder_path . "*.jpg", GLOB_BRACE);     
    if($images){ 
        foreach($images as $image){
            $src_match = "/" . $image;
            echo "<div class='masonry'><img class='photo' src='" . $src_match . "' alt='' /></div>";
        }
    } ?>
```

**CSS**

```
.masonry{width:25%;}
.masonry img{width:100%;height:auto;display:block;background:url("images/loading.gif") center center no-repeat;}
```

**jQUERY**

```
var $container = $('#photographs');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
$container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.masonry',
    columnWidth: '.masonry'
});
});
```

Thanks in advance

Mike

Comment: you NEED to provide what you have done so we can assist, ie provide your php code to read and list the images

Comment: Added my code so far to the question. I left it out intentionally so as to remain completely open to new ideas, but if this is the preferred method then that's what I will follow. Obviously there is no attempt at infinite scroll present. This is because I haven't found an ideal way to implement it yet.

Comment: Okay, so you have an array of images, what you could do on page load is pick the first 20 from the array.  Then what you would could do is have an on window.scroll event in your jQuery, which checks the current height of the image container and checks your Y offset, if you Y offset exceeds that of the image container, then run some AJAX code which updates the content area with another 20 images (so we would now be displayed 40 images)

Comment: What I've posted is really just a basic idea of how you can approach this problem, I'm writing from my phone atm so it's fairly hard to provide an answer, I hope this gives you some ideas though.

Comment: Thanks Alex. That sounds similar to a solution I saw elsewhere online, but if you could help me out with some code when you have the time then that would be excellent. The only thing stopping me from using this solution (assuming it is the same) was that I didn't quite understand how the pagination of images worked. As far as ajax goes, that's another new area to me, so any guidance you can offer is much appreciated.  Had to edit this comment three times as i am also typing on my phone and keep hitting "post" by mistake! If you saw an incomplete reply that sounded abrupt, that's why!

Comment: Okay so I had a look at the source code of [this demo of both plugins working together](http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/infinite-scrolling-demo1/). Am I right in thinking that I need to load a certain number of images from my array to my gallery page, and then load the rest (via Ajax?) into a new, blank page, which will serve as the "next page link" that Infinite Scroll requires?

Comment: Can anyone help with this?